# Deep-wrapping of JSON response objects in Ember Objects

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I am currently working on an Ember project where I fetch a complex JSON response in a `Route`'s `model` function. In the corresponding template, I display attributes of the response. For some of them, there are certain actions available which lead to changes on this model.

I want these changes to be directly reflected in the UI using Ember's binding. Unfortunately, while accessing a top-level response property in the `ObjectController` with `this.get('attributeFromJson')` works well, trying the same (or a `set`) on one of the child properties doesn't work.

I have produced the following JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/KkD6U/

My understanding is that I would need to convert the response into a `Ember.Object` manually in order to benefit from its `Ember.Observable` mixin.

My question is: is there any plain Ember way to automatically "deep-wrap" a whole JSON response into a structure of `Ember.Object` to use `get` and `set` on the whole response? What would be the plain Ember way to do this?

---

Update:

In the meantime, I built a trivial function to convert plain JS objects to Ember objects, see jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5vEcL/1/

Does it look feasible?

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that I would need to convert the response into a Ember.Object manually in order to benefit from its Ember.Observable mixin.

Basically yes, if you would wrap your child objects in a `Ember.Object.create(...)` it would work with ember's binding mechanism:

```
...
anArray: [
  Ember.Object.create({
    id: '1',
    anotherAttribute: '123'
  }),
  Ember.Object.create({
    id: '2',
    anotherAttribute: '456'
  })
]
...
```

See here your modified jsfiddle of the example above: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZFkA/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, intuitivepixel, that was the direction I was pushing into, too. I edited my question possibly while you were answering, see my enhanced jsFiddle at the end of the question. The basic problem is that a simple `Ember.Object.create(...)` does not seem to wrap nested arrays/objects, that's why I was specifically asking for a "deep-wrap".